# Creating a Javascript Confirm Box Based On Form Selection - PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a drop-down box on my HTML form as follows;

```
<select name="sequence" id="sequence" onchange="checkTHREE(this);">
              <option value="NONE">Select Type...</option>
              <option value="ONE" <?php if ($Sequence=='ONE') echo 'selected="selected"';?> >One</option>
              <option value="TWO" <?php if ($Sequence=='TWO') echo 'selected="selected"';?> >Two</option>
              <option value="THREE" <?php if ($Sequence=='THREE') echo 'selected="selected"';?> >Three</option>
          </select>
```

When 'THREE' is selected, I want a pop-up box to appear asking "Are you sure you want to select 'Three'?" I believe this is done using Javascript, something like;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkTHREE(element) {

      if (element.selectedIndex == 'THREE'){
       confirm("Are you sure you want to select 'Three'?")
    }
}
  </script>
```

And this javascript code goes in between the 'head' tags right?

I don't have a lot of experience with Javascript so apologies in advance for stupid questions!

-------SOLUTION--------

After making the following slight changes (changed '`element.selectedIndex`' to '`element.value`') to my javascript code, it worked :) ;

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkTHREE(element) {

          if (element.value == 'THREE'){
           confirm("Are you sure you want to select 'Three'?")
        }
    }
      </script>
```

Comment: You should put all your JS code and files loading at the end of your website (before `</body>`) to load page elements before JS (so the user will not wait for it to load).

Comment: _And this javascript code goes in between the 'head' tags right?_ No it has to be placed inside `body`

Comment: Ok thank you, I will move the code and see if I have any success. Does the code look alright to you or am I missing something?

Comment: Your `if` statement can be more simple: `if (element.selectedIndex == 3) {...}`

Comment: Also you have to make care about restoring previous selection in the case when user doesn't confirm change

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkTHREE(element) {

  if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'THREE'){
   confirm("Are you sure you want to select 'Three'?")
}
```

this function is not close by "}". You should add "}" to close function that is OK

Comment: This should be a comment, not answer